# Update query string parameter at socket.io reconnect

Tags: node.js, parameters, socket.io, reconnect

I pass a custom query string containing an ID to authorize a client on the server when he is connecting via socket.io.

```
var env = {id:12345};
var socket = io.connect('https://example.com', {query:'i='+env.id, port:443, reconnect:false, secure:true});
```

When a client disconnects for whatever reason, he can reconnect by simply calling the following function.

```
socket.socket.connect();
```

However, at the time of a reconnect `env.id` usually contains a different value than during the initial connect and I want to have the current value in the query string at each reconnect.

The above reconnect method sends the initial value again, even if `env.id` was changed to an other value meanwhile.

I tried to set the current parameters when calling the reconnect function, but that does not seem to work.

```
socket.socket.connect('https://example.com', {query:'i='+env.id, port:443, reconnect:false, secure:true})
```

Is there a simple way to update just the query string with the current `env.id` value and then reconnect?

Or do I need to destroy the entire socket object once disconnected and then build up a new connection using `var socket = io.connect()` with the current id?

Comment: The documentation gives an example on how to do this: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#with-query-option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I analyzed the socket object and found the solution, therefore I am answering my own question.

The query string is stored inside `socket.socket.options.query`. You can change it to the desired value directly before reconnecting.

```
socket.socket.options.query = 'i='+env.id;
socket.socket.connect();
```

Comment: How can I pass 2 parameters with query option? Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Try `socket.socket.options.query = 'i='+env.id+'&j='+env.j;`.  Put an `&` between them.

Comment: I might be wrong but I believe this behaviour breaks in v1.5

Comment: I'm using socket_io_client: ^2.0.3+1, the query is updated but not sent to the serverside. here is my code ``socket = socket_io.io(url, <String, dynamic>{'autoConnect': false, 'transports': ['websocket'],'query': "key=$param"});
socket.query="key1=$param1 & key2=$param2";
socket.disconnect().connect();``  please help.

Comment: I added "'force new connection': true," on ``socket = socket_io.io(url, <String, dynamic>{'autoConnect': false, 'transports': ['websocket'],'force new connection': true,'query': "key=$param"}); socket.query="key1=$param1 & key2=$param2"; socket.disconnect().connect();`` and it works.

Answer (score 11):

In the current version of socket.io (at the moment of writing is 1.3.7) you should use

`socket.io.opts.query = 'i='+env.id;`

But be careful of using this due [this bug](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1677)

Answer (score 2):

Using socket.io version 1.4.8 , I tried a bunch of things to get this to work, what ultimately worked for me was to set both socket.io.uri and socket.io.opts.query before calling connect() to reconnect

```
// Original connection
socket = io.connect('https://socket.example.com/?token=' + data.socket_auth_token, {
                            reconnection: false,
                            transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
                            'sync disconnect on unload': true
                  });

// Reconnect

socket.io.uri = 'https://socket.example.com/?token=' + data.socket_auth_token; 
socket.io.opts.query = 'token=' + data.socket_auth_token;
socket.connect();
```

And here is more code for context:

```
 <script src="//js/contrib/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        socket = io.connect('https://socket.example.com/?token=' + data.socket_auth_token {
            reconnection: false,
            transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
            'sync disconnect on unload': true
        });

        function reconnectSocket() {
            if (typeof socket != 'undefined' && !socket.connected) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/socket/',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        'action': 'generate_token',
                    },
                    dataType: 'json'
                }).done(function (data) {
                    socket.io.uri = 'https://socket.example.com/?token=' + data.socket_auth_token;
                    socket.io.opts.query = 'token=' + data.socket_auth_token;
                    socket.connect();
                });
            }
            setTimeout(reconnectSocket, 5000);
        }
        setTimeout(reconnectSocket, 5000);
    </script>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me somehow by only updating query parameters on reconnect, query parameters were not updating but with Uri change and query change it works. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me as of 2.0.3, I've tried changing socket.io.opts.query, socket.query, socket.io.uri and socket.uri :/

Answer (score 1):

For v2.1.1 I solved that by disconnecting and reconnecting after changing the query params:

```
socket.socket.query = { ...updated queries here}
socket.socket.disconnect().connect()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use reflection like this:

```
        Field field = Manager.class.getDeclaredField("opts");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Manager.Options options = (Manager.Options) field.get(socket.io());
        options.query = getQuery();
```